# Haskell convert list of list of strings to string

Tags: string, list, haskell, concatenation

I'm currently trying to pretty-print a list of list of strings as a single string. My current code is

```
pretty :: [[String]]->String
pretty x
   = concat(concat(x))

main :: IO ()
main
  = putStrLn (show (pretty [["hi","hi","hi"]]))
```

When asked to do `pretty [["hi","hi","hi"]]`, it converts it to "hihihi" but when asked `pretty [["hi","hi","hi"]["hi","hi","hi"]]` the compiler gives the following error

```
main.hs:7:29: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[[Char]] -> [String]'
              with actual type `[[Char]]'
* The function `["hi", "hi", "hi"]' is applied to one argument,
  but its type `[[Char]]' has none
  In the expression: ["hi", "hi", "hi"] ["hi", "hi", "hi"]
  In the first argument of `pretty', namely
    `[["hi", "hi", "hi"] ["hi", "hi", ....]]'
 |
  7 |   = putStrLn (show (pretty [["hi","hi","hi"]["hi","hi","hi"]]))
 |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys. It turned out I forgot the comma in [["hi","hi","hi"],["hi","hi","hi"]]